# Adding new date formats to ExtJS

Tags: extjs

[Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date) contains formats `a` and `A` for am/pm or AM/PM, respectively.

I want to add a format, call it `b`, for a/p without the m. I have searched parseFunctions and formatFunctions but did not find where the old format is defined.

Can anyone shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`formatCodes`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Date-property-formatCodes) in `Ext.Date`:

> The base format-code to formatting-function hashmap used by the format
>   method. Formatting functions are strings (or functions which return
>   strings) which will return the appropriate value when evaluated in the
>   context of the Date object from which the format method is called. Add
>   to / override these mappings for custom date formatting.